# What is the Difference Between Driving Force and Net Force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, drag

I'm a bit confused with the question below. Particularly, I'm confused what the difference between **driving force** and **net force** is.

For driving force, I easily find
$$F_D = ma = 1000 \times 0.3 = 300$$
Problem is, I'm inclined to find $F_{net}$ as,
$$F_{net} = F_{res} - F_D = 200N$$

The correct answer, however, is  $300N$.

[image]

Comment: IMO this is a legitimate question since it is asking to understand terminology.

Answer (score 1):

"Net force" is the sum of all forces acting on an object.

"Driving force" is just one specific force acting on the car in this problem.